# gitfs_remotes in salt, how to reference properly in the sls file? file is served but cant reference

Tags: git, salt-stack, gitfs

I am having a dilemma that salt documentation cant help me solve. I am trying to to get a file from a git repo and than manage file in the sls.
I have configured the master in the following way:

```
gitfs_provider: pygit2
fileserver_backend:
 - git
 - roots
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/
  dev:
    - /srv/salt/dev/
  int:
    - /srv/salt/int/
  qa:
    - /srv/salt/qa/
  stg:
    - /srv/salt/stg/
  prod:
    - /srv/salt/prod/
```

I have one remote specified:

```
gitfs_remotes:
- https://server.com/path/to/repo.git:
  - user: salt
  - password: salt
  - root: path/to/file/in/git
  - mountpoint: salt://dev
```

In my sls i have the following, and only entry:

```
jbiam.yaml:
 file.managed:
- name: /srv/salt/dev/files/application.yml
- source: salt://application.yml
- user: root
- group: root
- mode: 655
- template: jinja
- defaults:
    bla: "bla"
```

I execute highstate for the dev environment:

```
salt '*' state.highstate env=dev
```

now, not matter what i put in the source, path wise, it never finds the file
I am lost at the moment....
If i add the file into the root of the salt fs, things work as expected. but with gitfs it is just not working. If i remove the mount point from git remote config and run the highstate without the environment things work as expected, but as soon as I introduce the environment, it cant find the file

when i run salt-run fileserver.file_list i see the file listed:

```
salt-run fileserver.file_list
 [DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
 [WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
 [DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded fileserver.file_list
 [DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
 [DEBUG   ] Guessing ID. The id can be explicitly set in /etc/salt/minion
 [DEBUG   ] Found minion id from generate_minion_id(): bla
 [DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
 [DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master         /master_event_pub.ipc
 [DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master   /master_event_pull.ipc
 [DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
  [DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'fun': 'runner.fileserver.file_list', 'jid': '20160830220634591807', 'user': 'root', '_stamp': '2016-08-31T02:06:35.031018'}
 [DEBUG   ] pygit2 gitfs_provider enabled
 [DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded git.envs
 [DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded roots.envs
 [DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
 - .git/HEAD
 - .git/config
 - .git/description
 - .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
 - .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
 - .git/hooks/post-update.sample
 - .git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
 - .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
 - .git/hooks/pre-push.sample
 - .git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
 - .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
 - .git/hooks/update.sample
 - .git/index
 - .git/info/exclude
 - .git/logs/HEAD
 - .git/logs/refs/heads/master
 - .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
 - .git/objects/pack/pack-280ac298a92c1fde082a7d7d84da86d855720a3a.idx
 - .git/objects/pack/pack-280ac298a92c1fde082a7d7d84da86d855720a3a.pack
 - .git/packed-refs
 - .git/refs/heads/master
 - .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
 - .gitignore
 - dev/application.yml
 - dev/bootstrap.yml
```

However the I just cant reference it when i run it:

```
site.com:
  ----------
      ID: /srv/salt/dev/files/application.yml
Function: file.managed
  Result: False
 Comment: Source file salt://application.yml not found
 Started: 22:31:29.496613
Duration: 33.199 ms
 Changes:

 Summary for site.com
  ------------
 Succeeded: 0
 Failed:    1
  ------------
 Total states run:     1
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it with `dev` in the source URI?

```
jbiam.yaml:
  file.managed:
    - name: /srv/salt/dev/files/application.yml
    - source: salt://dev/application.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You never stated which git branch you are using. My guess is that you just have it in the "master" branch.

Keep in mind that gitfs maps branches/tags to fileserver environments. So when you ran [salt-run fileserver.file_list](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.fileserver.html#salt.runners.fileserver.file_list), you were listing the files in the `base` fileserver environment (which maps to the `master` branch).

When you later run using `env=dev` (note: newer Salt releases require `saltenv` instead of `env`), you are telling Salt to pull the file from the `dev` branch/tag.

My best guess here is that you have your files in the `master` branch, when you need them in a branch called `dev` to reference them using `saltenv=dev`.